# Combine dataframe with column value matching

Tags: python, pandas

How can I do for below expected result with python code?

```
[DF1]                                    [DF2]

**Name** **Configure**                 **Name**
MD0001       2G                         MD0001
MD0002       3G                         MD0001
MD0003       4G                         MD0001
                                        MD0002
                                        MD0002
                                        MD0003
                                        MD0003
                                        MD0003
```

Expected result:

```
Name    Configure
MD0001  2G
MD0001  2G
MD0001  2G
MD0002  3G
MD0002  3G
MD0003  4G
MD0003  4G
MD0003  4G
```

Here is my code so far:

```
data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(data,skiprows=1,sheet_name='KPI')
new_xlsx = pd.read_excel(new, skiprows=1,sheet_name='KPI')
data_df = pd.Dataframe[data_xlsx ]
new_xlsx = pd.Dataframe[new_xlsx ]
```

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(data,skiprows=1,sheet_name='KPI')  
new_xlsx = pd.read_excel(new, skiprows=1,sheet_name='KPI') 

data_df = pd.Dataframe[data_xlsx ]
new_xlsx = pd.Dataframe[new_xlsx ]


Then i don't know how to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use merge or join. This is pandas' way of accomplishing SQL-like joins.

```
# mock up the test dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    columns=["Name", "Configure"],
    data = [
        ("MD0001", "2G"),
        ("MD0002", "3G"),
        ("MD0003", "4G")
    ]
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    columns = ["Name"],
    data = [
        ("MD0001",),
        ("MD0001",),
        ("MD0001",),
        ("MD0002",),
        ("MD0002",),
        ("MD0003",),
        ("MD0003",),
        ("MD0003",)
    ]
)

# index df1 on Name
df1 = df1.set_index("Name")

# then join it to df2
df2.join(df1['Configure'], on="Name")
```

Output:

```
    Name    Configure
0   MD0001  2G
1   MD0001  2G
2   MD0001  2G
3   MD0002  3G
4   MD0002  3G
5   MD0003  4G
6   MD0003  4G
7   MD0003  4G
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what about if second DF2 columns header name is not "Name".

Comment: You would specify which column to "join on" by modifying the join method's "on" parameter in the last line.